# CSS how to make scrollable list

Tags: html, css, pug

I am trying to create a webpage which is made up of a header and bellow the header a list of items. I want the list of items to be vertically scrollable. I also would like the webpage to take up the entire window but not be bigger. Currently my problem is the list of items is not scrollable and instead extends far below the bottom of the window and this is causing the window to be scrollable. What should the *CSS* properties be on the *html*, *body*, *header* and *list items*?

```html
doctype html
html
    head
        link(href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet")
    body
        div#wrapper
            h1 Interactive Contact Directory
            div(class="tools")
                |Search: 
                br
                input(type="text" id="searchBox")
                select(name="searchBy" id="searchBy")
                    option(value='firstname') First Name
                    option(value='lastname') Last Name
                    option(value='email') Email
                br
                br
            div(id="listingHolder")
                ul(id="listing")
            div(id="listingView")
```

Bellow is the current style sheet I have

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background:#121212;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    max-height: 100%;
}
h1 {
    margin:0px;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:100;
}
.tools {
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}
#searchBox {
    padding:7px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:1.2em;
}
a.filter {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:5px;
    background:#0472C0;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:3px;
}
a.filter:hover {
    background:#0B9DE0;
    color:#fff;
}
ul#listing {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
}
ul#listing li {
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    display:block;
}
ul#listing li .list-header {
    padding:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
}

ul#listing li .list-header:hover {
    background:#7893AB;
    color:#fff;
}
ul#listing li .list-header.active {
    background:#447BAB;
    color:#fff;
}
ul#listing li .details {
    display:none;
    background:#efefef;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:0.9em;
}
#listingHolder{
    width: 50%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the list to fit the window vertically, or it will have a fixed height?

Comment: i want the list to fit take up as much vertical height as is possible without causing the window to be bigger than the browser window

Answer (score 162):

As per your question vertical listing have a scrollbar effect.

**CSS / HTML :**

```css
nav ul{height:200px; width:18%;}
nav ul{overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>header area</header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Link 1</li>
                <li>Link 2</li>
                <li>Link 3</li>
                <li>Link 4</li>
                <li>Link 5</li>
                <li>Link 6</li> 
                <li>Link 7</li> 
                <li>Link 8</li>
                <li>Link 9</li>
                <li>Link 10</li>
                <li>Link 11</li>
                <li>Link 13</li>
                <li>Link 13</li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <footer>footer area</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works great except how can i make the height of the nav be dynamic, such that it takes up as much space as it can but wont casue the page to be bigger than the window

Comment: okay to make it dynamic you can define max-height:100%; min-height:500px lets assume 500px; height:500px; here again the height property define for IE older browser.

Comment: ^did not work, it just caused the list to take up as much space as it needs and exeeds the window bounds

Comment: min-height:200px;height:200px; max-height:auto;
Here min-height is necessary to define. It tells that once the content exceed the 200px limit then show the scrollbar. max-height should be auto or 100%. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: best to use max-height and then it will not scroll until it needs to.

Comment: Also better to use overflow-y:auto; along with max-height

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be as below where the list is placed under a drop-down button.

```
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown"
    >Markets<span class="caret"></span></button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu", style="height:40%; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
      {{ form.markets }}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that OP load a massive CSS framework just to create a scrollable list?

Comment: No I am not however the snippet uses some bootstrap 4 if I am not mistaken